# Is there a way for EF to use database without permission to VIEW ANY DATABASE?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

The problem is our user cannot be granted permission to VIEW ANY DATABASE, nor CREATE DATABASE. So we've setup an account that is db_owner of the database and created blank database to fill.
Tested locally, above works only when we GRANT user to VIEW ANY DATABASE so won't apply in our target environment. My assumption was that EF is trying to establish whether database is already there, but since it cannot see any it'll always try to create one. Is there any way around it? Ideally - is there a setting that will tell EF that DB is there and there's no need to look for it?

Comment: Ef should not create a databae. And your connection string should point to a visible db as default database.

Comment: @TomTom is there a way to expose single database to the user? As I mentioned, the user has db_owner role for that database however it's not allowed to list.
I can see that first query EF is sending over is to check sys.databases which returns 0 because of that permission
````IF db_id(N'db name') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'db name'````

Comment: What version of EF?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it's EF 6.2.0

Comment: And what is the EF code that causes the query to sys.databases?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it's performed the moment DBContext is first time used to select from existing table (basically listing contents of DBSet)

Comment: "@TomTom is there a way to expose single database to the user? " Yes, but it is quite complicated. This is covered in various hosting guidelines for SQL Server (i.e. allowing a user only to see HIS databases). Standard SQL behavior is that a user always can see ALL Databases, but not work in them unless he has permissions. But he can always see that they are there as long as he can log into the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in EF6.  The code makes the incorrect assumption that db_id('dbname') works without VIEW ANY DATABASE.  It only works if the login running the query is *the* database owner.  Not a mere member of the DB_OWNER fixed database role.  I've [reported it](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1675), and suggesed an improvement.  But I'm not sure it will get fixed.

As a workaround just make the app user the real database owner.  That won't prevent sysadmins from connecting as dbo. eg

```
alter authorization on database::AppDatabase to Appuser
```

You'll have to drop the database user before making the login the owner.

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks for creating the report. I suppose that's as far as it can go towards resolving my issue.